# Missing properties file when i am running a java program from terminal

Tags: java, jar, terminal

To run my application i use the command

```
    java -jar "/home/stelios/NetBeansProjects/Askisi1/dist/Askisi1.jar"
```

However while i have the config.properties file in this directory

```
    "/home/stelios/NetbeansProjects/Askisi1/config.properties"
```

it runs normally in netbeans but when i try to run it from the terminal it produces this error

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:97)
    at askisi1.MainThread.main(MainThread.java:237)
```

What should be the correct location for my properties file?

Answer (score 1):

When you run you program from terminal your current folder becomes default folder for java app. So if you want your app to see `config.properties` you either need it to copy to current folder to go to `/home/stelios/NetbeansProjects/Askisi1/` and run app from there.

Comment: Is there an alternative so i can save the properties file somewhere e.g /src/ so i dont have to go to the current folder to run it?